# Syslog open once or for each log

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

I'm using Syslog for the first time to log my C/C++ application.

I want to know what is the berst practice, alwase open/close (with openlog and closelog) for each logging message, or open on the launch of the application and close at the end?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open on the launch of the application and close at the end